# jQuery validate two submit buttons

Tags: jquery, forms, function, validation, submit

I am trying to get two separate functions to fire depending on which submit button is pressed. When I click 'submit1', 'openMailer_1' appears in the console log, but then when I click 'submit2' 'openMailer_1' appears again, not 'openMailer_2'. Any idea what I've done wrong here?

```
$('*[id^=submit]').live('click', function() {

  var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
  console.log(id);  

  $('#result_form').validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form) { 
    //
    },              
    submitHandler: function(form) {             
      openMailer['openMailer_' + id](); 
    }
  });
});

var openMailer = {
  openMailer_1: function() {
    console.log('openMailer_1');    
  },

  openMailer_2: function() {
    console.log('openMailer_2');
  }
}


<form id="result_form" action="" method="post"> 
  <input type="submit" name="btn_send" id="submit1" value="submit1" />
  <input type="submit" name="btn_send" id="submit2" value="submit2" />
</form>
```

Comment: FYI: live is deprecated, use .on("click"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click event should be registered in `$(document).ready()` if it isn't. This will get the effect that you wanted, but there's more going on here.

You only need to call `.validate()` once at document load. This will register the validation rules for that form, and then you can use your submit handler to figure out which button was clicked. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ2mL/4/) for an example. Note that I declared `id` in global scope. There are probably many better ways of going about this, but it should point you in the right direction.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Jim, thank you very much for your time helping to explain this. You've helped me to learn where I was going wrong, many thanks.